# je change to jne and program issue

Tags: patching

I am new to forum and new to programming (total noob).

I am trying to modify a program using ollydbg and x32dbg and while attached to file I make the changes fine and it does what I expected.

My problem is saving the changes to file or patching in x32dbg does not work.
The second I make changes and save/patch I then rename original and move patched version into place and try to run the problems start.

First Windows 10 stops the file from running and at same time my malware and virus protection quarantines the file.
I know ollydgb and x32dbg are safe as I have used them before and my system is clean.

So is it because I did not disassemble the program first?
Or could the program have some sort of code that detected the changes made and then kills the program?

Thanks
Gren

Comment: Please post the assembly code you are modifying or the executable(s).

Comment: windows10 normally accepts only signed binaries when you patch thebinaries the signature is invalidated sowindows doesn't let you run them  and antivrus also normally check for the same